# Tirar caracteres no id

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Tenho um código que quando clica no botão para desativar foto ele faz desaparecer o botão que está do lado. Para conseguir fazer funcionar essa função, precisei passar no id uns caracteres antes, ficou assim:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="semEmi<?= $l->img_id ?>"></a>
```

no id essa parte que está escrita (semEmi) coloquei para que o botão fizesse sua função. Porém, quando eu vou clicar nesse botão, antes de desativar a foto, ele pega esses caracteres (semEmi), isso faz com que não funcione. Não sei como fazer para tirar esses caracteres ao clicar nesse botão. Meu código está em MVC

Aqui está o Javascript que faz as funções ao clicar nele:

```
$(document).on('click', '.semEmi', function () {
    var t = $(this);
    $.SmartMessageBox({
        title: "<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_title "); ?>",
        content: "<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_d "); ?>",
        buttons: "[<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_n "); ?>][<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_y "); ?>]",
        input: "text",
        inputValue: "",
        placeholder: "<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_place "); ?>"
    }, function (ButtonPress, Value) {
        if (ButtonPress == "<?= $this->lang->line("
        con_inflaud_jus_msg_btn_n "); ?>") {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (Value == "") {
                notifica('<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_title"); ?>', '<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_jus_msg_inpmpt"); ?>', 4000);
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Controller/Funcao/" + $(t).attr('id') + "/2",
                    data: {
                        justificativa: Value
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        if (r) {
                            $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.graf_lau').show();
                            $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.blockquote').show();
                            $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_d').show();
                            $(t).parent().parent().next().find('.img_lau_a').css('display', 'none');
                            $(t).removeClass('semEmi btn-default');
                            $(t).addClass('comEmi btn-warning');
                            $(t).empty();
                            $(t).append('<span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span><?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_afe_comEmi"); ?>');
                        } else {
                            notifica('<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_title"); ?>', '<?= $this->lang->line("con_inflaud_msg_erro_d"); ?>', 4000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Você quer que em `"Controller/Funcao/" + $(t).attr('id') + "/2"` o `id` contenha só os números, sem a string `semEmi`, é isso ?

Comment: isso mesmo @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: Use `$(t).attr('id').replace("semEmi", "")`